# The requested resource is not available in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts2, http-status-code-404

I am having **`The requested resource is not available`** error while running my Struts application on Tomcat.

**My directory structure is:**

[image]

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- remove these constant elements in production -->
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="app02a" namespace="" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Product_input">
            <result>/jsp/Product.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Product_save" class="app02a.Product" method="execute">
            <result>/jsp/Details.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

**`Web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5"> 

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Restrict direct access to JSPs. 
         For the security constraint to work, the auth-constraint
         and login-config elements must be present -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>JSPs</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

**Note:**

1.I have included all jars in lib folder and in they are in build path

2.I am using **struts-2.3.16.1**

3.I am trying to execute this url

```
http://localhost:8080/app02a/Product_input.action
```

Comment: Define "included all jars"; don't make us guess what you're deploying.

Answer (score 0):

In the `package` element, change the `namespace` to the "/":

```
<package name="app02a" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
...
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using struts-2.3.16.1, you should use

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

See the notes below the code at [Simple Example](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/web-xml.html#simple-example).

Answer (score 0):

Above mention  struts.xml “app02” package has some mistake according to mentioned URL

```
http://localhost:8080/app02a/Product_input.action
```

rather use struts default package it should be change like below mentioned way.

```
<package name="app02a" namespace="/app02a" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="Product_input">......</action>
  <action name="Product_save" class="app02a.Product" method="execute">....</action>
</package>
```